# How do I replace part of a string in PHP?

Tags: php

I am trying to get the first 10 characters of a string and want to replace space with `'_'`.

I have

```
  $text = substr($text, 0, 10);
  $text = strtolower($text);
```

But I am not sure what to do next.

I want the string

> this is the test for string.

become

> this_is_th

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Answer (score 171, accepted):

Simply use [str_replace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
$text = str_replace(' ', '_', $text);
```

You would do this after your previous `substr` and `strtolower` calls, like so:

```
$text = substr($text,0,10);
$text = strtolower($text);
$text = str_replace(' ', '_', $text);
```

If you want to get fancy, though, you can do it in one line:

```
$text = strtolower(str_replace(' ', '_', substr($text, 0, 10)));
```

Comment: I find the "fancy" version easier to read. It's worth noting that the order of `strtolower` and `str_replace` doesn't matter unless the replacement strings depend on lowercase or uppercase characters.

Answer (score 8):

You can try

```
$string = "this is the test for string." ;
$string = str_replace(' ', '_', $string);
$string = substr($string,0,10);

var_dump($string);
```

Output

```
this_is_th
```

Answer (score 5):

This is probably what you need:

```
$text = str_replace(' ', '_', substr($text, 0, 10));
```

Answer (score 4):

Just do:

```
$text = str_replace(' ', '_', $text)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need first to cut the string in how many pieces you want. Then replace the part that you want:

```
 $text = 'this is the test for string.';
 $text = substr($text, 0, 10);
 echo $text = str_replace(" ", "_", $text);
```

This will output:

> this_is_th