# Replacing php realpth when outputing to users

Tags: php, directory

I used php `real path` to get actual path of files and directory to delete and after deleted i will print all deleted 
items. But my problem is that it also show the real path where the file source is and i don't want to show it to users
is there any way i can hide the pay and only show the file example.

I don't like it to look like this

> [File]: /mnt/wef66/d2/81/557642661/htdocs/useruploads/myfiles/imagefolder/mosaic_1.jpg
>
> [File]: /mnt/wef66/d2/81/557642661/htdocs/useruploads/myfiles/imagefolder/room_home_1.jpg
>
> [Directory]: /mnt/wef66/d2/81/557642661/htdocs/useruploads/myfiles/imagefolder

Is there anyway i can make it look this way using rejex or any method please i need help i have to remove `/mnt/wef66/d2/81/557642661/htdocs/`

> [File]: www.example.com/useruploads/myfiles/imagefolder/mosaic_1.jpg
>
> [File]: www.example.com/useruploads/myfiles/imagefolder/room_home_1.jpg
>
> [Directory]: www.example.com/useruploads/myfiles/imagefolder

Maybe using something like this

```
echo preg_replace("/mnt/wef66/d2/81/557642661/htdocs", "www.example.com", "[File]: /mnt/wef66/d2/81/557642661/htdocs/useruploads/myfiles/imagefolder/mosaic_1.jpg");
```

`$path = realpath($parentBas);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I replace part of a string in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12605060/how-do-i-replace-part-of-a-string-in-php)

Comment: @Dekel please this is somehow different because i need it loop through all the deleted files  and also know here to start please i just need help i have tired to get it done

Comment: If you have the deleted files in a variable - just loop over this variable and replace the string you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use configuration variables `$privatePath` and `$publicPath`.

So you can concat whichever you want to the relative paths to your directories or files.

For your example:

```
$privatePath = '/mnt/wef66/d2/81/557642661/htdocs/';
$publicPath = 'www.example.com/';

$pic1RelativePath = 'useruploads/myfiles/imagefolder/mosaic_1.jpg';

$pic1privatePath = $privatePath . $pic1RelativePath;
// /mnt/wef66/d2/81/557642661/htdocs/useruploads/myfiles/imagefolder/mosaic_1.jpg

$pic1publicPath = $publicPath . $pic1RelativePath;
// www.example.com/useruploads/myfiles/imagefolder/mosaic_1.jpg
```

I think this is easier and more efficient than replacing the paths with regex.

EDIT:

If you have all the real paths in an array, you can loop through it and replace easily all the private paths with the public paths this way:

```
$paths = [
'/mnt/wef66/d2/81/557642661/htdocs/useruploads/myfiles/imagefolder/mosaic_1.jpg',
'/mnt/wef66/d2/81/557642661/htdocs/useruploads/myfiles/imagefolder/room_home_1.jpg',
'/mnt/wef66/d2/81/557642661/htdocs/useruploads/myfiles/imagefolder'
];

foreach ($paths as &$path) {
  $path = str_replace($privatePath, $publicPath, $path);
}

print_r($paths);
```

Comment: how this will work? the whole path come in one string and he you just cut it into 2 i can't see anything to use here

Comment: Ok, maybe I didn't understand well the problem. I've added an example to easily replace the paths if you have them stored in an array. Hope it helps.