# WP Is converting & to &amp; in usernames in the comments

Tags: php, wordpress, function, comments

**Where:** In the Comments / Usernames of the commentor
**What:** Usernames with "&" become "& a m p ;" 
**Related plugin in use:** [AnyComment](http://anycomment.io/en/) (Uses default WP-User for names)

I have tried (and successfully) manually changing the Ampersand via "Better Search and Replace" plugin, but this does not do it automatically whenever a new user signs up with such a name. 

I'm not a full-fledged developer and have only very basic knowledge of PHP and so I do hope someone could help me out here. This only happens in the comments part. 

Is there a plugin / code that could "force" all "& a m p ;" to become "&"? Or to automatically convert it from the database as it's created?

Huge huge thanks in advance!

Comment: In my experience with Wordpress. It is not possible to make a post that doesn't get parsed into markup without having some sort of administrator role.
https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#unfiltered_html

Answer (score 0):

Use the html decode in `PHP`

```
$str = "$amp;";
echo htmlspecialchars_decode($str);
```

[Link to doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php)

or [str_replace()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12605060/how-do-i-replace-part-of-a-string-in-php)

Comment: I tried copying this into my child-theme's function file and it didnt quite work. It also "broke" the comment plugin xD ... Not sure if i did something wrong... I literally just pasted it in there