# If mobile number starts with +270 then replace with 27

Tags: php

I need some code for a PHP project. I need to correct mobile number formats that we receive incorrectly on occasion into our API. If the number starts with +270 then it needs to be replaced with 27 and still preserve the rest of the number

Comment: Already voted to close as Too Broad, but this also appears to be a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12605060/how-do-i-replace-part-of-a-string-in-php

Comment: Ok, go ahead. What do you need us for?

Comment: Sounds like a nice challenge. Good luck!

Comment: how is this to broad?

Comment: I know @Dharman but I figured (guessed) it was probably at the start of the string and the + wasn't likely to be repeated.

Comment: yes so I only need to replace at the start of the string and only if it matches exactly +270

Comment: @code-is-life Could you read this section, please? [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$phoneNumber = preg_replace("(^\+270)", "27", $phoneNumber);
```

Simple as that.